# How to read key input?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I am trying to have a key control camera. There is no Onkeypress for TForm so how can i read this input from keyboard?

```
procedure TForm2.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
var
  ok: boolean;
begin
  ok := true;
  case Key of
    'a': camera1.Position.y:=camera1.Position.y+1;
    'A': camera1.Position.y:=camera1.Position.y+1;
    'd': camera1.Position.y:=camera1.Position.y-1;
    'D': camera1.Position.y:=camera1.Position.y-1;
    'w': camera1.Position.X:=camera1.Position.X-1;
    'W': camera1.Position.X:=camera1.Position.X-1;
    'x': camera1.Position.X:=camera1.Position.X+1;
    'X': camera1.Position.X:=camera1.Position.X+1;
    'q': camera1.RotationAngle.z := camera1.RotationAngle.z-1;
    'Q': camera1.RotationAngle.z := camera1.RotationAngle.z-1;
    'e': camera1.RotationAngle.z := camera1.RotationAngle.z+1;
    'E': camera1.RotationAngle.z := camera1.RotationAngle.z+1;
    'z': camera1.Position.z:=camera1.Position.z+1;
    'Z': camera1.Position.z:=camera1.Position.z+1;
    'c': camera1.Position.z:=camera1.Position.z-1;
    'C': camera1.Position.z:=camera1.Position.z-1;
    else
      ok := false;
  end; {case}
  //if ok then
   // Invalidate;
  positionChange(camera1);
  RotationAngleChange(camera1);
end;
```

Comment: TForm have event OnKeyDown and OnKeyUp (XE3, XE4).

Comment: using xe2  ill add that tag :(

Comment: OnKeyDown is missing in events also

Comment: So the documentation lies about existing [`OnKeyDown`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/FMX.Forms.TCommonCustomForm.OnKeyDown) ? Strange, so probably you'll need to override the `KeyDown` method like shown in [`this thread`](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=60054).

Comment: if its there i dont see it, i may have to try that thread...here is what i see  http://postimg.org/image/f6zqa6rav/

Comment: @TLama I think the documentation is very true ... and tells about events that are **public**, but they have to be **published** to be visible inside OI

Comment: Ok *XE2 Update 4 Hotfix 1* and there are a lot more events visible in OI `OnKeyDown`,`OnKeyUp`,`OnMouse...` so this question targets a fixed bug

Comment: @Sir Rufo, nice catch! I missed that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update to the latest version of XE2 (AFAIK Update 4 Hotfix 1) and

use `TForm.OnKeyDown` or `TForm.OnKeyUp` events instead. Here's a quick test I used:

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  case KeyChar of
    'A'..'Z', 'a'..'z': Caption := 'Got an alpha ' + KeyChar;
    '0'..'9': Caption := 'Got a number ' + KeyChar;
  else
    Caption := 'Got something else ' + KeyChar;
  end;
  KeyChar := #0;
end;
```

According to this [Embarcadero forums post](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=60054), in XE2 without the update above you need to actually override the `TForm.KeyDown` event (added per @TLama's request; he's the one who located it and posted in the comments to my answer):

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
  private
  public
    procedure KeyDown(var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char; 
      Shift: TShiftState); override;
  end;

implementation

procedure TForm1.KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  case KeyChar of
    'A'..'Z', 'a'..'z': Caption := 'Got an alpha ' + KeyChar;
    '0'..'9': Caption := 'Got a number ' + KeyChar;
  else
    Caption := 'Got something else ' + KeyChar;
  end;
  KeyChar := #0;
end;
```

(Just as a note, you can shorten your code somewhat):

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  ok := true;
  case KeyChar of
    'A', 'a': camera1.Position.y:=camera1.Position.y+1;
    'D', 'd': camera1.Position.y:=camera1.Position.y-1;
    'W', 'w': camera1.Position.X:=camera1.Position.X-1;
    'X', 'x': camera1.Position.X:=camera1.Position.X+1;
    'Q', 'q': camera1.RotationAngle.z := camera1.RotationAngle.z-1;
    'E', 'e': camera1.RotationAngle.z := camera1.RotationAngle.z+1;
    'Z', 'z': camera1.Position.z:=camera1.Position.z+1;
    'C', 'c': camera1.Position.z:=camera1.Position.z-1;
  else
    ok := false;
  end; {case}
  if ok then
  begin
   // Invalidate;
   KeyChar := #0;  // Remove keystroke, because you've handled it
  end;
  positionChange(camera1);
  RotationAngleChange(camera1);      
end;
```

Comment: Treid that just now , same thing... and i have added a showmessage() to see if that event is even being called and its not.  Also dont see formkeydown or formkeyup in the object inspector under events

Comment: Then you have something else going on, because (as I said) I tested with the code I posted, and watched the caption update as I typed a letter, a number, and an `@` sign.

Comment: did you test with fmx and xe2?

Comment: Wait. I stand corrected. It's not in XE2 (I missed that tag, and mistakenly used XE4). I'll delete my answer shortly, unless I can find a workaround.

Comment: @Ken - I'm pretty sure I used FMX on XE2 to test this, as I don't have any newer version.

Comment: I am not lieing :D  i added all this and it runs but never triggers.. btw here is the object inspection..  http://postimg.org/image/f6zqa6rav/

Comment: @Sertac: It could be; my XE2 won't start a new FMX project (something broke it with XE3 or XE4 on this machine, apparently - I never start it anymore for FMX because it's so bad in XE2), so I can't test there. I did find a workaround on the EMBT forums (thanks to TLama); if he doesn't post an answer, I'll update mine.

Comment: @TLama: Nice catch. It appears that's a solution to the problem. If you'll write an answer (you can just grab my code if you want to use as a base), I'll delete my answer afterward.

Comment: @SirRufo: Thanks for the edit regarding the update. I added a fix for those that don't have it for some reason as well.

Comment: I had help from TLama and Sir Rufo putting the pieces together. :-)